# Symfony autowire @required method with event dispatcher never called

Tags: symfony

Considering this following service class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Listener\Entity;

use AppBundle\Entity\Payment;
use AppBundle\Event\PaymentEvent;
use AppBundle\Event\PaymentEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

final class PaymentEntityListener
{
    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    /**
     * @required
     *
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher
     */
    public function setEventDispatcher(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        dump($eventDispatcher);
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    /**
     * @param Payment $payment
     */
    public function postPersist(Payment $payment)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(PaymentEvents::ADD, new PaymentEvent($payment));
    }
}
```

The method `PaymentEntityListener::setEventDispatcher` should be call with the `EventDispatcherInterface` matched service.

This method is correctly configured according to the debug command:

```
$ ./bin/console debug:container --show-private AppBundle\\Listener\\Entity\\PaymentEntityListener

Information for Service "AppBundle\Listener\Entity\PaymentEntityListener"
=========================================================================

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                            
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       AppBundle\Listener\Entity\PaymentEntityListener  
  Class            AppBundle\Listener\Entity\PaymentEntityListener  
  Tags             -                                                
  Calls            setEventDispatcher                               
  Public           no                                               
  Synthetic        no                                               
  Lazy             no                                               
  Shared           yes                                              
  Abstract         no                                               
  Autowired        yes                                              
  Autoconfigured   yes                                              
 ---------------- -------------------------------------------------
```

But this method is never called.

Here is my `services.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: legacy_aliases.yml }

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false

    _instanceof:
        Doctrine\ORM\Decorator\EntityManagerDecorator:
            public: true

    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    PowerDNSBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/PowerDNSBundle/*'
        exclude: '../../src/PowerDNSBundle/{Entity,Repository}'

    PowerDNSBundle\Doctrine\ORM\PowerDNSEntityManager:
        arguments:
            $wrapped: '@doctrine.orm.powerdns_entity_manager'
```

I don't know why the method is not called and why Symfony does not throw any exception.

FYI, the following command:

```
./bin/console debug:container --show-private Symfony\\Component\\EventDispatcher\\EventDispatcherInterface
```

Does return a service match.

Where can be the issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: for anyone reading: the debug:container command is really helpful. In my case I had a clash with JMS DI (during porting from JMS to Symfony DI) which seemed to be stripping the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found why: This listener didn't have the correct tag:

```
AppBundle\Listener\Entity\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Listener/Entity'
    tags: ['doctrine.orm.entity_listener']
```

Because of that, I guess the service is not recognized by Doctrine and this one try to create the listener itself. But in this case, the method will never be called.